# Avoid "past"dates with UIDatePicker

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

I have a question about UIDatePicker. Is it possible to avoid to select past dates? I mean, select only day from today to the following days, avoiding to select the  "past".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
[datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
```

This will just set the minimum date to the current date (returned by `[NSDate date]`).